# Implementing ListView in home screen widget

Tags: android, android-widget

How to make widget with something like ListView. I've made it using LinearLayout but I don't know how to discover amount of rows. (I want to know exact amount of rows to make widget able to paging)

I want it to look like this (photoshop and copypast):

[image]

Notes:

1. Android 2.3.4 and below.
2. widget of size 4x4

UPDATE AND CLARIFICATION:

When I said "scrollable" I mean scroll by click on UP and DOWN buttons (you see it on the screenshot) ie paging

Comment: Does your ListView contain more data than is shown or do you simply want to cover the wallpaper for the entire 4x4?

Comment: I dynamically fill ListView while it have available space (294 max). I take 294 from formula cellNumber*74 - 2. I want to cover entire 4x4 but don't know how to calculate it size

Comment: I haven't worked with widgets much, but the ListView won't draw items unless they are visible. It seems like you are doing unnecessary work. What happens when you simply bind the ListView with the adapter without trying to limit anything to 294dp?

Comment: No in widgets before 3.0 (or 3.1) there is no ListView, actually I fill GroupView row by row

Comment: I don't get it, is the image above showing what is wrong or what you expect?

Comment: It's wrong.cause I fill only 9 rows or 294 dp of the screen. Because I don't know actual size of the widget

Comment: Am close to solution, can you Give me some more data to solve this ..!
what do you mean by 4x4, do you want to fill the whole screen in to 16equal parts?
Can you create an image & show how should your Output want to be.
i think i can solve this issue.

Comment: @VenomVendor I want to fill all space that available in 4x4 cells of the home screen.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know how to determine real size the widget 4x4 in dp. It seems that it can be determined only by knowing the specific device.

You can scroll by fixed number of rows.

Answer (score 1):

The only pre 3.0 example with source I know of is the [ScrollableContacts](http://code.google.com/p/scrollablecontacts/) project on Google Code. It features a scrollable list in a home screen widget and works from 2.1. However, the widget requires a home replacement - see the project description. The source can be viewed [here](http://code.google.com/p/scrollablecontacts/source/browse/).

Comment: The solution that you have offered is not working because 294dp is just request of 4x4 cells of the home screen. It's not actual size of the widget. For example we have device with 800px/480px and density 160. By formula "px = dp*(dpi/160)" we have actual height 800 dp. Not 294dp.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include how to get dpi and screen size in pixels.

Comment: Your solution could work only if display 4x4, and all home screen space is given to widget. But actually there is a lot of devices has more than 4x4 screen and on every device which I saw there is menu buttons on the bottom of the screen. So I could not calculate widget size from screen size using your solution.

Comment: You are right. I've deleted the part of my answer which dealt with dpi calculations as my solution would only work for a subset of screen sizes. Sorry I couldn't be of better help:)